Why @click and @paste show diff props
here is my demo Vue SFC Playground
in component Comp, I do the same thing, log the props.id
when I click comp, the id is correct
but when i hover and paste the id always the same until i move mouse out for a while
I want know why and how to get the correct id when I do the paste

You copy something, then you paste it. How would a hover change that? You're mostly pasting what's in your pastebin. Also what do you want to achieve by using the @paste listener?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Use @mouseenter to set a global currently hovered component:
See on Vue SFC Playground
<script>
import {ref, getCurrentInstance, onUnmounted} from 'vue';
const current = ref();
</script>

<script setup>
const props = defineProps({id: Number})
const self = getCurrentInstance();
const $me = ref();

const click = () => {
  console.log('click', props.id)
}

const onPaste = (event) => {
  alert('onPaste: ' + props.id);
}

defineExpose({
  onPaste
})

onUnmounted(() => {
  if(self === current.value){
    current.value = null;
  }
});

</script>

<template>
  <div style="width: 100%;height: 100%" @click="click" 
  @paste.prevent="current?.exposed.onPaste($event)" @mouseenter="current = self" @mouseleave="current = null">
    id: {{ id }}
  </div>
</template>

